# Media query on DIV ID

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I'm using the below CSS to force the footer to the bottom of the page

```
#bump {
margin-top: 50px;
height:150px;
}

#footer {
padding-top: 5px;
min-height: 150px;
background-color: #284602;
color: #ecf0f1;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width: 100%;
}
```

This works fine on a medium or large screen device, on a smaller device however the footer can end up over the content (responsive footer grows and effectively doubles in height on a small device).  So I thought I could use a media query at the end of my style.css with this:

```
// Small devices (landscape phones, less than 768px)
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {


#bump {
    margin-top: 50px;
    height:300px;
}
#footer {
    padding-top: 5px;
    min-height: 300px;
    background-color: #284602;
    color: #ecf0f1;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
}

}
```

Its not working though - have I misunderstood something?  The media query is at the end of my document, and looking at the developer tools it still considers height to be 150PX on a small screen.

Thoughts pls?  Thanks

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with that, assuming you're talking about the `#bump` element. Are you sure it's this that's giving you the height you're expecting, i.e is it inheriting its height from children? Pure guess without seeing the functioning html but try adding `display: block` and see what happens.

Comment: Lewis - The website is http://breakingborderline.co.uk/ and i've tried now just setting the background to red via body.  I'm still not sure its even registering the media query.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you try removing the comment beginning with `// small devices`? It looks like it doesn't like that comment.

Comment: Thank you so much Lewis.  Updated and its working.  How did you find that please?  Did i miss something?

Comment: I ran your CSS through this: https://codebeautify.org/cssvalidate and it flagged the comment. I'm not sure why it doesn't like that to be honest, I thought // ignored the whole line.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed!

Comment: In CSS comments have to be written as `/* .... */` - one-line comments with `//...` like in PHP or JS don't exist in CSS